# getting back to folder in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, button, click, back

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     Response.Redirect("Page2.aspx");
}
this is code to go on .aspx but what if i want to go in Folder in my solution explorer, tried with location but it dont work
Who knows post it.

this is location >
website\admin
-news.aspx
-project.aspx
and i created in news.aspx button go back to admin, and when i hit button location is next > website\admin\admin why he  duplicate admin ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have admin folder in your application then redirect it

> Response.Redirect("admin/page.aspx"); or
>   Response.Redirect("~/admin/page.aspx");

if you don't have admin folder in your application then redirect it

> Response.Redirect("page.aspx");

Try this all ...

Comment: i try it , same error

http://ploader.net/files/5e7b025418cf73db6328228cbbad11a1.JPG
here is tree view from news.apsx i have button to redirect me to admin folder

Comment: Response.Redirect("~/admin");
This is how should be write, no need for all path to folder.

Comment: but now I have another problem ,when i add button to project.aspx i get this error

CS1061: 'ASP.admin_project_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'Button1_Click' and no extension method 'Button1_Click' accepting a first argument of type 'ASP.admin_project_aspx' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

????

Answer (score 1):

```
Response.Redirect("~/Folder/Page.aspx");
```

The tilde `~` is very useful for redirects, it signifies your site root.  So wherever you are on the site, you can redirect to folders relative to the domain root.  I hope this is what you meant!

Comment: it's still locate me on website/admin/admin

Comment: but i dont wont to redirect me to .aspx site i want to locate me on Folder